# Sangria Default value for Enum Inputs causes "sangria.schema.SchemaValidationException:"

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

I'm trying to execute an introspection query against a schema having  optional Enum input and a default value for it.

Below is a sample code

```
sealed abstract class Weekday(val order: Int) extends EnumEntry with Ordered[Weekday] {
  def compare(that: Weekday) = this.order - that.order
}

object Weekday extends Enum[Weekday] {
  val values = findValues

  case object Monday extends Weekday(2)
  case object Tuesday extends Weekday(3)
  case object Wednesday extends Weekday(4)
  case object Thursday extends Weekday(5)
  case object Friday extends Weekday(6)
  case object Saturday extends Weekday(7)
  case object Sunday extends Weekday(1)
}

case class WeekDayContainer(weekDay: Weekday)

object WeekDayContainer{
  val default =  WeekDayContainer(Weekday.Monday)
}
//Input Object
case class Context(id: Int, name: String, weekDayContainer: WeekDayContainer = WeekDayContainer.default)

//Macro derivation
implicit val WeekdayInputType: EnumType[Weekday] = deriveEnumType[Weekday](
    EnumTypeName("Weekday")
)

implicit val WeekContInputType: InputObjectType[WeekDayContainer] = deriveInputObjectType[WeekDayContainer]()

implicit val pcInputType: InputObjectType[Context] = deriveInputObjectType[Context]()

val contextArg = Argument("Context", pcInputType, description = "context of the xyz")
```

Below is the stacktrace

```
Invalid default value of field 'weekDayContainer' in input type 'Context'. Field 'Context.weekDayContainer.weekDay' has wrong value: Enum value expected.
        at sangria.schema.SchemaValidationRule$.validateWithException(SchemaValidationRule.scala:41)
        at sangria.schema.Schema.<init>(Schema.scala:918)
        at SchemaDefinition$.<init>(SchemaDefinition.scala:215)
        at SchemaDefinition$.<clinit>(SchemaDefinition.scala)
        ... 111 more
[ERROR] [SECURITY][11/28/2018 03:48:34.306] [sangria-server-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(sangria-server)] Uncaught error from thread [sangria-server-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3]: null, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[sangria-server]
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at Server$$anonfun$executeGraphQL$1.apply(Server.scala:31)
        at Server$$anonfun$executeGraphQL$1.apply(Server.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.RouteDirectives$$anonfun$complete$1.apply(RouteDirectives.scala:47)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.RouteDirectives$$anonfun$complete$1.apply(RouteDirectives.scala:47)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.StandardRoute$$anon$1.apply(StandardRoute.scala:19)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.StandardRoute$$anon$1.apply(StandardRoute.scala:19)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRouteResult$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:59)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRouteResult$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:59)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.FutureDirectives$$anonfun$onComplete$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(FutureDirectives.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.FutureDirectives$$anonfun$onComplete$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(FutureDirectives.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$$anonfun$transformWith$extension0$1.apply(FastFuture.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$$anonfun$transformWith$extension0$1.apply(FastFuture.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.akka$http$scaladsl$util$FastFuture$$strictTransform$1(FastFuture.scala:41)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.transformWith$extension1(FastFuture.scala:45)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.transformWith$extension0(FastFuture.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.FutureDirectives$$anonfun$onComplete$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(FutureDirectives.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.FutureDirectives$$anonfun$onComplete$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(FutureDirectives.scala:35)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$textract$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:152)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$textract$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:152)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:42)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.FutureDirectives$$anonfun$onComplete$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(FutureDirectives.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.FutureDirectives$$anonfun$onComplete$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(FutureDirectives.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$$anonfun$transformWith$extension0$1.apply(FastFuture.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$$anonfun$transformWith$extension0$1.apply(FastFuture.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.akka$http$scaladsl$util$FastFuture$$strictTransform$1(FastFuture.scala:41)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.transformWith$extension1(FastFuture.scala:45)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.transformWith$extension0(FastFuture.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.FutureDirectives$$anonfun$onComplete$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(FutureDirectives.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.FutureDirectives$$anonfun$onComplete$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(FutureDirectives.scala:35)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$textract$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:152)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$textract$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:152)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.FutureDirectives$$anonfun$onComplete$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(FutureDirectives.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.FutureDirectives$$anonfun$onComplete$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(FutureDirectives.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$$anonfun$transformWith$extension0$1.apply(FastFuture.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$$anonfun$transformWith$extension0$1.apply(FastFuture.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.akka$http$scaladsl$util$FastFuture$$strictTransform$1(FastFuture.scala:41)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.transformWith$extension1(FastFuture.scala:45)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.transformWith$extension0(FastFuture.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.FutureDirectives$$anonfun$onComplete$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(FutureDirectives.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.FutureDirectives$$anonfun$onComplete$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(FutureDirectives.scala:35)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$textract$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:152)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$textract$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:152)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.FutureDirectives$$anonfun$onComplete$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(FutureDirectives.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.FutureDirectives$$anonfun$onComplete$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(FutureDirectives.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$$anonfun$transformWith$extension0$1.apply(FastFuture.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$$anonfun$transformWith$extension0$1.apply(FastFuture.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.akka$http$scaladsl$util$FastFuture$$strictTransform$1(FastFuture.scala:41)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.transformWith$extension1(FastFuture.scala:45)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.transformWith$extension0(FastFuture.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.FutureDirectives$$anonfun$onComplete$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(FutureDirectives.scala:37)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.FutureDirectives$$anonfun$onComplete$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(FutureDirectives.scala:35)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$textract$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:152)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$textract$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:152)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRouteResult$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:59)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRouteResult$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:59)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$textract$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:152)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$textract$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:152)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:47)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.akka$http$scaladsl$util$FastFuture$$strictTransform$1(FastFuture.scala:41)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.transformWith$extension1(FastFuture.scala:45)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.flatMap$extension(FastFuture.scala:26)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:42)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRequestContext$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:41)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRequestContext$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:41)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$textract$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:152)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$textract$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:152)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$textract$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:152)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$textract$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:152)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:42)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:47)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.akka$http$scaladsl$util$FastFuture$$strictTransform$1(FastFuture.scala:41)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.transformWith$extension1(FastFuture.scala:45)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.flatMap$extension(FastFuture.scala:26)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:42)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRouteResult$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:59)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRouteResult$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:59)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRouteResultWith$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:65)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRouteResultWith$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:65)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$textract$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:152)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$textract$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:152)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.ExecutionDirectives$$anonfun$handleExceptions$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ExecutionDirectives.scala:32)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.ExecutionDirectives$$anonfun$handleExceptions$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ExecutionDirectives.scala:28)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$textract$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:152)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$textract$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:152)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route$$anonfun$asyncHandler$1.apply(Route.scala:86)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route$$anonfun$asyncHandler$1.apply(Route.scala:85)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsync$$anon$25.onPush(Ops.scala:1190)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:519)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:411)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:588)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:472)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:563)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:745)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:760)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:670)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:588)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:557)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: sangria.schema.SchemaValidationException: Schema does not pass validation. Violations:

Invalid default value of field 'weekDayContainer' in input type 'Context'. Field 'Context.weekDayContainer.weekDay' has wrong value: Enum value expected.
        at sangria.schema.SchemaValidationRule$.validateWithException(SchemaValidationRule.scala:41)
        at sangria.schema.Schema.<init>(Schema.scala:918)
        at SchemaDefinition$.<init>(SchemaDefinition.scala:215)
        at SchemaDefinition$.<clinit>(SchemaDefinition.scala)
        ... 111 more
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding a Decoder it works fine

```
  private val stringEncoder = implicitly[Encoder[String]]
  private val stringDecoder = implicitly[Decoder[String]]

  implicit val ChargeTypeEncoder: Encoder[Weekday] = new Encoder[Weekday] {
    override def apply(enum: Weekday): Json = stringEncoder.apply(enum.entryName)
  }

  implicit val ChargeTypeDecoder: Decoder[Weekday] = new Decoder[Weekday] {
    final def apply(c: HCursor): Result[Weekday] = stringDecoder.apply(c).flatMap { s =>
      val maybeMember = Weekday.withNameOption(s)
      maybeMember match {
        case Some(member) => Right(member)
        case _ =>
          Left(DecodingFailure(s"$s' is not a member of enum $Weekday", c.history))
      }
    }
  }
```